# Selecting all the check-boxes at once in Shiny

Tags: r, widget, shiny

I would like to know how to select all the check-boxes at once. In my code I have Five check-boxes.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100),
      checkboxInput("checkbox1", label = "meanSNR", value= FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox2", label = "t-statistics", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox3", label = "adjusted p-value", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox4", label = "log-odds", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox5", label = "All", value = FALSE)),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to know how to make it work

1) If the user selects the fifth check-box `All`, It should automatically select all the check-boxes. On uncheck, it should deselect all the Checkboxes.

2 ) If the user selects the first four check-boxes, it should select the fifth one `All` check-box too.

For condition 1) , the screen should like this
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't nearly as elegant as Jorel's answer, but it's a solution that uses pure `shiny` package code.

```
    library(shiny)
#* make sure to include session as an argument in order to use the update functions
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })

  #* This observer will update checkboxes 1 - 4 to TRUE whenever checkbox 5 is TRUE
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$checkbox5,
    handlerExpr = 
    {
      if (input$checkbox5)
      lapply(paste0("checkbox", 1:4),
             function(x)
             {
               updateCheckboxInput(session, x, value = input$checkbox5)
             }
      )
    }
  )

  #* This observer will set checkbox 5 to FALSE whenever any of checkbox 1-4 is FALSE
  lapply(paste0("checkbox", 1:4),
         function(x) 
          {
            observeEvent(
              eventExpr = input[[x]], 
              handlerExpr = 
              {
                if (!input[[x]]) updateCheckboxInput(session, "checkbox5", value = FALSE)
              }
            )
          }
  ) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100),
      checkboxInput("checkbox1", label = "meanSNR", value= FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox2", label = "t-statistics", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox3", label = "adjusted p-value", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox4", label = "log-odds", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox5", label = "All", value = FALSE)
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Some follow up and recommendations

I spent a little time trying to get the application to do what you've specified, but honestly, it felt pretty unnatural (and wasn't working particularly well).

1. In a checkbox, if you check "All", it implies that you wish to check all the boxes, but I don't think unselecting "All" necessarily implies unselecting all of the boxes.
2. Stemming from 1), you're trying to have one control do two different things, which can open the door to confusion.

So here's my recommendation: User four checkboxes and two buttons.  The two buttons control if you select all or unselect all of the boxes, and they act independently.

```
library(shiny)
#* make sure to include session as an argument in order to use the update functions
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs), col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })

  #* This observer will update checkboxes 1 - 4 to TRUE whenever selectAll is clicked
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$selectAll,
    handlerExpr = 
    {
      lapply(paste0("checkbox", 1:4),
             function(x)
             {
                 updateCheckboxInput(session = session, 
                                     inputId = x, 
                                     value = TRUE)
             }
      )
    }
  )

  #* This observer will update checkboxes 1 - 4 to FALSE whenever deselectAll is clicked
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$deselectAll,
    handlerExpr = 
    {
      lapply(paste0("checkbox", 1:4),
             function(x)
             {
                 updateCheckboxInput(session = session, 
                                     inputId = x, 
                                     value = FALSE)
             }
      )
    }
  )


}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 10, max = 500, value = 100),
      checkboxInput("checkbox1", label = "meanSNR", value= FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox2", label = "t-statistics", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox3", label = "adjusted p-value", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("checkbox4", label = "log-odds", value = FALSE),
      actionButton("selectAll", label = "Select All"),
      actionButton("deselectAll", label = "Deselect All")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `Error: unexpected symbol in:" shinyApp"`

Comment: Sorry.  I lost the closing `)` for `sidebarPanel`.  It should work now.

Comment: Thanks, but works partially `1) ` On uncheck of `All` not deselecting others  `2) `  On checking first four, not selecting the fifth i e . `All`.

Comment: @AaghazHussain Perhaps you would be better served with action buttons over checkboxes for this behavior.  See my follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this on JS side. I'd get every checkBox like this 
`var cbx1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');` etc. and i'll store them in an array
i'll also have a function that will check everything :

```
checkEverything = function(){
    cbx1.val = "true";
    cbx2.val = "true"; 
    // etc..
}
```

And i would bind this function on the 4th checkbox onclick event. I'd also have a function that check if every is checked like :

```
checkIfEverythingChecked = function(){
   if(cbx1.val == true && cbx2.val == true)
      cbx4.val = true; 
}
```

And i'd bing this on the onclick event of every checkBox

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It would be deemed to be an answer if it works . I would be pleased if you make it working.

Comment: Please tell me how it went :)

Comment: I don't know JS, so did not try.